# I get wrong page type from template

Tags: page, google-api

I need to get the current page type, but i get the wrong type. for example, in home, i use this

```
$this->getAction()->getFullActionName();
```

And sometimes i get `catalog_category_view`, sometimes i get `catalog_product_view`

But, in the body tag I get the right classes

```
<body class=" cms-index-index cms-home" id="mainbody">
```

Comment: I disabled cache and the issue  just gone, when I enable the cache the problem appears again. but I don't now the reason why  wether we are using php code. I've tried  a lot ways to do it, with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
$handler = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles();
echo $handler[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code will work in observer to get full action name

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        $module = $request->getControllerModule();
        $module_controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $module_controller_action = $request->getActionName();

        $fullActionName = $module."_".$module_controller."_".$module_controller_action;

        echo $fullActionName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()); ?>
```

it should give you a current layout handle.